# Prove that $G$ is isomorphic to $\text{Inn}(G)$ if $G$ has trivial center $Z(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know the isomorphism is $F: G \rightarrow \text{Inn}(G)$ defined as $F(a) = \phi_a$ where $\phi_a(x) = axa^{-1}$ but I'm not sure how to use the assumption (that $G$ has trivial center) to prove injectivity and surjectivity. I got as far as showing it was a homomorphism but just having trouble with the last part. This is what I have for the proof of a bijection:

Suppose $G$ is a group such that $Z(G) = \{e\}$ and let $F : G \rightarrow \text{Inn}(G)$ be defined by $F(a) = \phi_a$. I claim that $F$ is injective by proving that if $F(a) = F(b)$, then $a=b$ (i.e. that $F(a)$ and $F(b)$ are the same function). Suppose for some $a,b,x \in G$ with $x \neq e$ that $F(a)(x) = F(b)(x) \implies \phi_a(x) = \phi_b(x) \implies axa^{-1} = bxb^{-1} \implies ax = bxb^{-1} a \implies x = a^{-1} bxb^{-1} a \implies a^{-1} b = e \implies b = a$.

Do I need to make any other assumptions on my choice of $x$ (should I even assume $x \neq e$?) or $a$ and $b$?

We have not discussed quotient groups or kernel and I would like to prove it by showing that $F$ is a bijective homomorphism.

Comment: Rather than checking that $F(a) = F(b) \implies a = b$, you should use the fact it is a group homomorphism to check the simpler condition $F(a) = \mathrm{id} \implies a = \mathrm{id}$. Of course, both methods are correct, but the second is more efficient.

Comment: Does this prove that $F$ is injective? I'm not sure I understand why that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

The center $Z(G)$ is the kernel of $F$.

Comment: We haven't really discussed kernel, and I feel more comfortable proving it's a bijective homomorphism

Comment: Very well.   When you get to the _first isomorphism theorem_ maybe revisit this problem,  for a nice application.

Answer (score 0):

To prove injectivity, you need to show that $F(a) = F(b)$ implies $a = b$. Of course if $F(a) = F(b)$, then $\mathrm{id} = F(a)F(b)^{-1} = F(ab^{-1})$. Thus, it suffices to show that if $F(x) = \mathrm{id}$, then $x = e$. Of course, if $F(x) = \mathrm{id}$, then $F(x) = \phi_x = \mathrm{id}$.

So, for all $a\in G$, we have $a = \mathrm{id}(a) = \phi_x(a) = xax^{-1}$. Multiplying on the right by $x$ gives $ax = xa$, again for all $a\in G$. Thus $x$ belongs to the center of $G$, and is thereby equal to $e$, since we assumed that $Z(G)$ is trivial.

The map $F$ is obviously a surjection, by definition of $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$. Hence $F$ is a bijective group homomorphism, and therefore an isomorphism, as desired.

Comment: How is it obviously a surjection by the definition of Inn(G)? Is it due to the fact that we proved it is a $1-1$ mapping or am I missing something in the definition? It makes sense I just want to be rigorous.

Comment: @Trigginometric: Each element of $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$ is an element of the form $\phi_x$ for some $x\in G$. Clearly $\phi_x = F(x)$ with the definition of $F$. This has nothing to do with whether or not $F$ is 1-1.

Comment: Yes that is clear now. Thank you very much.